# Is set SetROP2 valid for printer device?

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I draw/print every second line of a table with a highlighted pen.

```
CPen pen(PS_SOLID,nPenWidth,crPrint);
CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&pen);            
pDC->SetROP2(R2_MASKPEN);
pDC->MoveTo(rc.left+m_cxPrinter,y);
pDC->LineTo(rc.right-m_cxPrinter,y);
pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
```

The problem I have now is that with certain printer, this covers all of the underlying text so that no text can be seen.

Same issue with "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer.

From [CDC::SetRop2](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(AFXWIN%252FCDC%253A%253ASetROP2)%3Bk(CDC%253A%253ASetROP2)%3Bk(SetROP2)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160#setrop2) Remarks:

> The drawing mode is for raster devices only; it does not apply to vector devices. Drawing modes are binary raster-operation codes representing all possible Boolean combinations of two variables, using the binary operators AND, OR, and XOR (exclusive OR), and the unary operation NOT.

I do not think this can be, because a pdf Printer is not a vector device?

--

**Edit**:
add additional code to test it for everyone:

```
void CTestPrintView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CTestPrintDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    int static c = 0;
    
    // Resourcen select
    CFont* pOldFont = (CFont*)pDC->SelectStockObject(DEVICE_DEFAULT_FONT);

    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    pDC->GetTextMetrics(&tm);
    int m_cxPrinter = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
    int m_cyPrinter = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;


    ////////////////////
    // Print this
    //
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format(L"%d Hello, can you Print me? ", c++);
        pDC->TextOut(x, y += m_cyPrinter, str);

        if (i % 2)
            DrawLineColor(pDC, CRect(x, y - m_cyPrinter / 2, x + m_cxPrinter * 80, y + m_cyPrinter));
    }

    pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
}


void CTestPrintView::DrawLineColor(CDC* pDC, const CRect& rc)
{
    // Print Ok in Preview
    // Fails with some printers and with "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer

    long y = rc.top;
    int nPenWidth = rc.Height(); // / 2;
    CPen pen(PS_SOLID, nPenWidth, RGB(187, 255, 255));
    CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
    int nOldROP = pDC->SetROP2(R2_MASKPEN);
    pDC->MoveTo(rc.left, y);
    pDC->LineTo(rc.right, y);
    pDC->SetROP2(nOldROP);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
}
```

Comment: `GetDeviceCaps` with index `TECHNOLOGY` should give you information if it is classified as raster device. You can also drop raster operations if you have solid background. Just calculate final color as `final_color = pen_color & background_color` (I think it is correct for `R2_MASKPEN`) and use this value in `CPen` constructor.

Comment: `GetDeviceCaps` give me the correct information `DT_RASPRINTER` for "Microsoft Print to PDF". What I see, PrintPreview show always the correct content with SetRop2, Print covers the underlying text.

Comment: My experience has been that results are more dependable if you start by drawing everything into a memory DC, then just do a simple copy from there to the printer.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this too in a memoy DC, with the same result.  I will add code so everyone can test this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 11 months, the problem still exist, but I found now a lovely hack to solve this issue. At the end of DrawLineColor() Just Invert the line **2x** with `InvertRect(rc)`

```
    .. 
    pDC->SetROP2(nOldROP);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);

    // Don't remove this 2 lines of code! 
    // I do not know why this works, but this solve some Printer Drivers Problems (incl. Microsoft Print to PDF)
    pDC->InvertRect(rc);        // ***
    pDC->InvertRect(rc);        // ***
}
```